# How does the bottom participant steer in two-man luge?

Tags: technique, luge

Based on this statement, found [here](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/4098/527):

> Typically, the 2-man luge is slower because they start further down on
>   the track, but it is much harder to steer because the man on top is
>   the only one that can see, but the man on the bottom is the one that
>   is most able to contribute to the steering.

**How does the bottom participant steer in two-man luge?** Since the top participant is the only one that can see down the track, how does the bottom participant know when to steer and in what direction?

I notice there are handles from the top participant's suit the bottom participant grabs onto...does this have any significant effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bottom driver is like the suspension for the sled, resulting in a smoother travel. And yes, the handles for the bottom athlete are significant too. The top  man who sees the track signals the man in bottom (mostly using head movement) to help steer.

Read this article for more info: http://www.slate.com/blogs/five_ring_circus/2014/02/13/doubles_luge_sochi_games_2014_what_do_the_two_men_do_in_two_man_luge.html

Comment: +1 Thanks for the answer. This is a good way to summarize the article you reference to answer my question in your own words without changing what the article says. Good work.